# How to pass values between functional components in ReactJS using Navlink?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I'm am new to React and this is my first project.

I am trying to pass the *id* (which comes from `item.id`) of a transaction located in my `Summary` functional component to my `EditTransaction` functional component.

It is giving me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

I've tried:

But it does not seem to work either...

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from "./views/Home";
import Summary from './views/Summary';
import Profile from './views/Profile';
import Groups from './views/Groups';
import About from './views/About';
import Transaction from './views/Transaction';
import Signin from "./components/Signin";
import EditTransaction from "./views/EditTransaction";


import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/Signin" component={Signin} />
          <Route exact path="/About" component={About} />
          <Route exact path="/Profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route exact path="/Groups" component={Groups} />
          <Route exact path="/Summary" component={Summary} />
          <Route exact path="/Transaction" component={Transaction} />
          <Route exact path="/EditTransaction/:id" component={EditTransaction} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Summary.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import EditTransaction from '../views/EditTransaction';
import SigninNavBar from '../components/SigninNavBar';

function Summary(){

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [trans, setTrans] = useState([]);

  const [signin, setSignin] = useState({signin:localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false});
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({username:"", email:"", password:""});

  console.log("Token: " + localStorage.getItem('token'));

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://34.94.76.5/api/transactions/get/", options)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log(response.status);
        setError(response);
      }
      response.json().then(data => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setTrans(data);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return (<Redirect to="/Signin" />);
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <SigninNavBar />
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Member ID</th>
              <th>Created</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
          </thead>
            {trans.map(item => (
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td> {item.id} </td>
                    <td> {item.member_id} </td>
                    <td> {item.created} </td>
                    <td> {item.category} </td>
                    <td> {item.description} </td>
                    <td> {item.amount} </td>
                    <td>
                      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                        <NavLink className="text-white" to={{ pathname:`/EditTransaction/${item.id}`, state:{id: item.id} }}>
                          Edit
                        </NavLink>
                      </Button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            ))}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Summary;
```

EditTransaction.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import moment from 'moment';

import  SigninNavBar from '../components/SigninNavBar.js';
import  Summary from '../views/Summary.js';

var currentDate = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss");

function EditTransaction(props) {

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [trans, setTrans] = useState([]); 
  const [tranUpdated, settranUpdated] = useState({id:0, member_id:'', category:'', description:'', amount:0}); 
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const [tran, setTran] = useState([]);

  
  //GET request for specific id
  const optionsGET = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://34.94.76.5/api/transactions/get/" + this.props.location.state + "/", optionsGET)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log(response.status);
        setError(response);
      }
      response.json().then(data => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setTrans(data);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  //PUT request to API for transaction
  const optionsPUT = {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(tranUpdated)
  }

  const updateTransaction = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("http://34.94.76.5/api/transactions/get/" + this.props.location.state + "/", optionsPUT)
    .then((response) => console.log('reponse: ' + response.json()))
    .then((message) => console.log('message: ' + message))
  }

  if (error) {
    return (<Redirect to="/Signin" />);
  } else{
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <SigninNavBar />
        <form>
          <h1>Update Transaction</h1>
          {trans.map(item => (
            <div className="form-horizantal">
              <fieldset>
                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label className="col-md-12"><p>{currentDate}</p></label>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label className="col-md-12">
                    <p>Member ID {item.member_id}</p>
                    <input type="text" name="member_id" placeholder={item.member_id} onChange={e => settranUpdated({ ...tranUpdated, member_id: e.target.value })} />
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label className="col-md-12">
                    <p>Transaction ID</p>
                    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder={item.id} onChange={e => settranUpdated({ ...tranUpdated, id: e.target.value })} />
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label className="col-md-12">
                    <p>Category</p>
                    <input type="text" name="category" placeholder={item.category} onChange={e => settranUpdated({ ...tranUpdated, category: e.target.value })} />
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label className="col-md-12">
                    <p>Description</p>
                    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder={item.description} onChange={e => settranUpdated({ ...tranUpdated, description: e.target.value })} />
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label className="col-md-12">
                    <p>Amount</p>
                    <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder={item.amount} onChange={e => settranUpdated({ ...tranUpdated, amount: e.target.value })} />
                  </label>
                </div>
              </fieldset>

              <button type="submit" onClick={updateTransaction}>Update</button>
            </div>
           ))}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditTransaction;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `this` keyword in a function component

Comment: Change `this.props.location.state` to just `props.location.state.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `this` keyword in a function component

Consider changing `this.props.location.state` to just `props.location.state.id`